# What is $B'_L$ and why is it equal to 1?

Tags: notation

I understand all the other ones, but the $B'_L$ has me stumped. What does it mean and why is it equal to 1?

[image]

Comment: This is a very nice clock. I recall a question about this on MathOverflow. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22266/what-is-the-mathematical-meaning-of-this-symbol

Comment: I don't know, I got the digital one.

Comment: If it is a mathematical clock, shouldn't it be $0$ at the extreme right ($\theta=0$)?  And shouldn't the hands move "counterclockwise" with appropriate renumbering?

Comment: I have a watch with that symbol and, like the original poster, it was the only one I couldn't figure out. I agree that it appears to be Legendre's constant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems this is [Legendre's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_constant)

$$
  B^\prime_L = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left ( \log n - \frac{n}{\pi(n)} \right)
$$

where $\pi(n)$ stands the number of primes not exceeding $n$.

Comment: You may be right, but this one seems to be the odd one out among the very basic writings of the other numbers...

Comment: Álvaro Lozano-Robledo says in his MO answer that $B$ comes from Legendre, speculates that the subscript $L$ was added as a tribute to Legendre, and expresses puzzlement on the source of the apostrophe.