# Random math questions (modular arithmetic & notation)

Tags: notation, modular-arithmetic

I found this amazing wall clock picture on the internet but I really don't know a few things. I don't know what's $B'_L$, `&#x33;`, why $2^{-1}\equiv 4[7]$ and the one with the black and white circles.

For $B'_L$, I thought first that it could be Bernoulli numbers but figured it out that it was something completely different. For $2^{-1}\equiv 4[7]$, I've been thought modular arithmetic but never with fractions or inverses, so it doesn't make much sense to me. For the last one, I thought it was braille but found out that numbers was completely different.

So can anyone explain me what are these?

[image]

Comment: Here ... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57458/what-is-b-l-and-why-is-it-equal-to-1

Comment: `&#x33;` is the HTML entity with code point `0x33 = 51`, which is the digit '3'. $2^{-1} \pmod{7}$ is the modular inverse of $2$ modulo $7$, which is $4$. `0x0B` is hexadecimal $11$. "the one with the black and white circles" is a binary notation $1\cdot 2^3 + 0\cdot 2^2 + 0\cdot 2^1 + 0\cdot 2^0 = 8$.

Comment: In binary, 8 is 1000. Since $2*4 = 8 = 1$ modulo 7, we can write $4 = 2^{-1}$ mod 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the first two. But for the last two...

Actually, it is $2^{-1} \equiv 4 \pmod 7$. For $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, $x^{-1}$ is the unique real number such that $xx^{-1} = x^{-1}x = 1$. So $2^{-1}$ modulo $7$ is the unique number (modulo $7$) such that $2\times2^{-1} = 2^{-1}\times 2 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$. As $2\times 4 = 4\times 2 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$, $2^{-1} \equiv 4 \pmod 7$.

As for the dots, think about binary where a black dot is a one and a white dot is a zero.

Answer (score 4):

I actually own this physical clock.  It came with a small slip of paper explaining each number as follows (hyperlinks added):

> Geek Clock Cheat Sheet
>
> 1) [Legendre's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_constant) is a mathematical constant occurring in a formula conjectured by Adrien-Marie Legendre to capture the asymptotic behavior of the prime-counting function.  Its value is now known to be exactly 1.
>
> 2) A joke in the math world: An infinite number of mathematicians walk into a bar.  The first one orders a beer.  The second orders half a beer.  The third, a quarter of a beer.  The bartender says, "I get it" and pours two beers.
>
> 3) A [unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) [sic] character [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) "[numeric character reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference)."
>
> 4) [Modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), also known as clock arithmetic, is a system of arithmetic for integers, where numbers "wrap around" after they reach a certain value.  The [modular multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of 2 (mod 7) is the integer /a/ such that 2*/a/ is congruent to 1 modulo 7
>
> 5) The [Golden Mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) ... reworked a little.
>
> 6) Three factorial 3*2*1
>
> 7) A repeating decimal that is proven to be exactly equal to 7 with [Cauchy's Convergence Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_convergence_test).
>
> 8) A graphical representation of a [binary, or base-2 number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number)
>
> 9) An example of a base-4 number, which uses the digits 0, 1, 2 and 3 to represent any real number.
>
> 10)A [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), also known as the choose function.  5 choose 2 is equal to 5! divided by (2!*(5-2)!)
>
> 11) [A hexadecimal, or base-16, number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)
>
> 12) A radical
>
> Design by [eagleapex.com](http://eagleapex.com/de/math-clock/)